# Does allocating pages with alloc_pages allocate also structs?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Let's consider this code:

```
struct page * str_page = alloc_pages(some flags, 4);
str_page++;
```

In the first line there are 16 pages going to be allocated and a pointer to `struct page` of first allocated page is saved into `str_page`.
Then I increment this pointer and it points now behind this structure.
Is it pointing now to `struct page` of the second allocated page?

General question is:
**Does structs for all allocated pages are also allocated with `alloc_pages()` or these structs are actually allocated earlier by kernel and handled by it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Is it pointing now to struct page of the second allocated page?

Usually it's. Mainly because alloc_pages allocates contiguous pages ( vs sparse/scattered ) and it only make sense to implement it this way.

However, I would advise you against doing that. If you want get the struct page of a specific physical page, you should use pfn_to_page/phys_to_page instead ( and obviously page_to_phys/page_to_pfn for the reverse operation ). I don't think there's any guarantee how the struct pages are laid out in memory.

> > Does structs for all allocated pages are also allocated with alloc_pages() or these structs are actually allocated earlier by kernel and handled by it?

They are just references to a pre-allocated pages. The actual pages were allocated at boot-time by the kernel and are managed by the kernel ever since.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to suggest the pages are contiguous:

http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch11lev1sec3

That implies that incrementing the str_page pointer will increment the value by the size str_page, giving you the next page in memory.

In c, that's how it works.  When you increment a pointer to a type, you increment the address of the pointer by the size of that type